# PyInstaller FileNotFoundError "scipy.libs"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my python project into an exe with PyInstaller

`pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=win32timezone --add-data "./data;data/" .\serviceWrapper.py`

But when trying to execute I get the following error on importing linear_model from scikit-learn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serviceWrapper.py", line 12, in <module>
    from main import main
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    import src.stromAufskalierungDE as stromAufskalierungDE
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "src\stromAufskalierungDE.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn import linear_model
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "scipy\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
  File "scipy\__init__.py", line 67, in _delvewheel_init_patch_1_1_0
  File "os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: 'C:\\Users\\07945A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI552362\\scipy.libs'
```

in english it'd be: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\07945A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI552362\\scipy.libs'`

It seems to be missing something from the scipy module, I tried to include `--hidden-import=scipy` and `--hidden-import=scipy.libs`, but that also didn't help.

How can I include this scipy.libs?

Comment: just sharing with you my experience using pyinstaller. I had a pretty similar issue before where it failed eventhough I've installed all libraries. Not too sure if the errors are the same as yours. what i did was reinstall python, meaning i made sure that all the installed libraries and scripts are removed completely. Then i strictly install only the libraries that I need and then it works. A more convenient way is to install the required libraries to a separate environment, meaning different folder path. then try to build using this new environment/path. You can consider as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Option

```
--add-data "path/to/venv/Lib/site-packages/scipy.libs;scipy.libs/"
```

solved this problem for me.